# Prevent website from resizing

Tags: css, html

On the website I'm currently fixing there are two divs displayed Inline.

On resizing the browser window, the div on the right automatically aligns to fit under the first div instead of staying inline. My question is on how to prevent this resize and to keep it standard on all screen sizes.

To display this issue, I've attached two screenshots.

[image: On maximum screen size]

[image: On reducing the browser window]

Another issue: The screen is vertically scrollable which should not be the case as the height of `html`, `body` or any of the `div` are not more than 100%

My CSS for the two main divs is as follows:

```
#menu{
  position:absolute;
  width:15%;
  height:600px;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#content{
  position: absolute;
  height:600px;
  width:73%;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 290px;
}
```

The CSS for the inner 4 divs are as follows

```
.gallery-image-rest{
    background: url('../images/thumbs/rest.jpg');
    position: relative;
    height:600px;
    width:24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    text-align: center;
    }
.gallery-image-replenish{
    background: url('../images/thumbs/Replenish.jpg');
    position: relative;
    height:600px;
    width:24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left:3px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    text-align: center;
    }

.gallery-image-rejuvenate{
    background: url('../images/thumbs/Rejuvenate.jpg');
    position: relative;
    height:600px;
    width:24%;
    float: left;
    margin-left:3px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    text-align: center;
    }

.gallery-image-reunite{
    background: url('../images/thumbs/reunite.jpg');
    position: relative;
    height:600px;
    width:24%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:3px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    text-align: center;
    }
```

The code has a lot of redundancies but that is second priority as the client needs the display to be correct before anything else.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting the size to a fixed proportions because you want to keep the text inside some boxes makes the site more difficult for some people to use. I have my browser set at 125% zoom by default, so that I can, with some difficultly, read the text on most sites that I visit.  Ideally I'd like it to be bigger but so many sites don't take this into account and the sites become unusable. The fact that there are people with poor eyesight, or just older people who find it harder to read small text these days never seem to occur to them. They can read it so everything is right with the world.

I would suggest that if you do alter your design that you use percentages for your width of your content and you should also use percentages for your margins / padding, rather than fixed PX values. That way your site would have held its general layout  and the text would have zoomed making easier to read, for people like myself.

```
#menu{
    position:absolute;
    width:15%;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 0.5000%;
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    height:600px;
    width:73%;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 16%;
}
```

And for each of your inner divs change all the margin-left:3px; to

```
margin-left:0.5000%;
```

Comment: I agree. In the end, I WILL have to redesign the site in the end, but for a temporary fix to the older code, I still need suggestions

Answer (score 5):

Specifying a `min-width` to your `<body>` element will prevent auto-resizing.

```
body {
    min-width: 1280px; // change width as needed to fit your page
}
```

Comment: I may have to redesign the whole website from scratch I feel. Because there're so many issues. The `min-width` didn't work, any idea why? All i did was add the `<body>` style  in my css and made it `min-width:1280px;`. It still resizes.